# jQuery Autocomplete - last row is 'hidden' within the div

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, client-side

I am using a jQuery autocomplete on our site, it works fine except occasionally some of the rows returned from the autocomplete cannot be seen, they are almost hidden within the div it is contained in.

What is the easiest/best solution to bring this forward so it can display all the rows and overlap the containing div.

My CSS

```
.autocomplete-suggestions {
    background-color: #79BE28;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
    max-height: 650px !important;
    width: 520px !important;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion {
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.autocomplete-suggestions .autocomplete-suggestion strong {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.autocomplete-suggestion {
    z-index: -1 !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="appendTo">
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999; width: 269px; display: block;">
<div data-index="0" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t Ives Nursery, 15 Needingworth Road, St. Ives, Cambridgeshire, PE275JP, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="1" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t Thomas More Catholic Primary School, Marsland Road  Hesters Way, Cheltenham, , GL510HX, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="2" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t James' Primary School, Moorgreen Road, West End, Southampton, Hampshire, SO303EG, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="3" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t Pius X Catholic High School, Wath Wood Road, Wath upon Dearne, Rotherham, South Yorkshire, S637PQ, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="4" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t Benedict Catholic School, Duffield Road, Darley Abbey, Derby, Derbyshire, DE221JD, United Kingdom</div><div data-index="5" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>t Cecilia's Wandsworth CofE School, Sutherland Grove, London, Greater London, SW185JR, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="6" class="autocomplete-suggestion"><strong>Sain</strong>tfield High School, 21 Comber Road, <strong>Sain</strong>tfield, Ballynahinch, County Down, BT247BB, United Kingdom</div>
<div data-index="7" class="autocomplete-suggestion">My school is not listed</div></div>
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions" style="position: absolute; display: none; max-height: 300px; z-index: 9999;"></div>
```

Comment: You can give `overflow-y:auto` to the container of the results!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak feel free to give that as answer for me too accept

Comment: can you create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `overflow-y:auto` to the container of the results which is `.autocomplete-suggestions`

The more amount of results will not be hidden as you can scroll it to the end wit the following code:

```
.autocomplete-suggestions {
    background-color: #79BE28;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
    max-height: 650px !important;
    overflow-y: auto; /* Add this */
    width: 520px !important;
}
```

*Why `auto`?*: Because if you can set it to scroll it will show scrollbars vertically even it the contents are not there! so setting it to `auto` will show scrollbars when needed!

Answer (score 1):

i do not have the complete code for your page but you can use overflow-y property to add a scroll bar to the container div like this:

```
.autocomplete-suggestions {
  background-color: #79BE28;
  border-radius: 7px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px #CCCCCC;
  max-height: 650px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* property added */
  width: 520px !important;
}
```

if you want to show the scroll bar only when there is more items that is not in view. you can set the property to auto. but this will make the scroll bar to show and hide when the data change which will make an awful shift of the content that most users will hate. if i have your whole page code i can tell you how to make the suggestions div show all with no scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript : document.getElementById("myDIV").style.overflow="scroll";

In Css you can use overflow property :    `overflow:scroll;`

In jQuery you can set overflow as  `$('#someid').attr('name', 'value');`